# Ajax issue when loading json-file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am saving a json string to local storage with setItem and get it back with getItem. This works, but when loading the same json string via ajax the object is becoming different.

Here is the original **object** in google-chrome browserconsole:

```
collection_parameter: Object
->OFFLINE: Array s
  ->_byId: Object
  ->models: Array[500]
..
```

Here is the **stringified json** (getItem, setItem) local-storage:

```
   {"OFFLINE":[{ "data_type":"OFFLINE",
                 "Number":"1",
                 "val_param_1_2_3":0 }, 
               {..},
               {..} ]
   }
```

When I am saving the above json-string in a file e.g. called Test.json and load it via ajax the object is not the same anymore.

Here the **ajax** call:

```
  $.ajax({                                    //Laden
        url:      'Test.json',
        method:   'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(recieved_json_parameters) {

            collections_parameter=recieved_json_parameters;


        }//end success
    });//end ajax
```

The **new object** collection_parameter in google-chrome is now:

```
collection_parameter: Object
->OFFLINE: Array [500]
```

The additional nodes are missing. What can I do to get the exact same object-type as above??

---

UPDATE1: This is how I create the original json:

```
var collections_parameter = { OFFLINE: Backbone.Collection.extend() }
collections_parameter.OFFLINE = new collections_parameter.OFFLINE(json);
```

Comment: the nodes are missing even when you click to expand the array? do you mean the `_byId` and `models` attributes are missing, or something else? Are these part of the `OFFLINE` or are they part of the `collections_parameter`? They do not appear in you stringified json example.

Comment: yes, they are missing. the nodes **_byId** and **models** is created by backbone I guess. They are part of the node OFFLINE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store a Backbone `Collection`, you should save the raw data the collection has, which you can get with `toJSON()`: (the returned value is an array of objects)

```
collection.toJSON() /* store the object returned by this function */
```

(In your case, I think the collection is `collection_parameter.OFFLINE`)

After retrieving the JSON representing the data, create a new Backbone `Collection` initialized with it:

```
collection = new MyCollection(json)
```

where MyCollection is the subclass of `Backbone.Collection` you're using, or `Backbone.Collection` itself, and `json` is the object you retrieved.

---

The reason for this is that you need to store the actual data represented by the `Collection`. The `Collection` object itself provides you functions for accessing and changing the underlying data, but it's not the data itself, and therefore it should not be serialized and stored. After retrieving the raw data, you create a new `Collection` that will provide you the various functions for accessing the data.

Comment: Thank you, but there is still a little difference. `collections_parameter.OFFLINE = new Backbone.Collection(json.OFFLINE);` gives me `__proto__:  e.Collection` instead of `__proto__: s`

Comment: @frankschmidt How did you create the original object? Also, does this difference affect the object? Is it missing any methods or behaves differently?

Comment: Please see the Update1. I can not for sure say, that it behaves the same.

Comment: Save your collection class outside the object: `var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend();`.
Then, use `collections_parameter.OFFLINE = new MyCollection(json);` when you create the original object and when you restore it from local strorage.